# How to check if three dimensional surface has endpoints

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

A big part of my calculus class is using Lagrange multipliers to find max/min values of a given function subject to some constraint. One thing I'm struggling with however, is that the endpoints of your given constraint curve are supposed to be considered as potential maxima/minima. This is trivial for some curves, and quite easy to see doesn't exist for constraints like spheres as they evidently have no endpoints, but there are some curves that I cannot visualize endpoints for.

For example, the constraint $z^{2} = xy +1$. I have a hard time visualizing it, and drawing it out is time consuming.  My question is, how can I check for whether this kind of curve indeed has endpoints or not as simply as possible?

Comment: Get any CAS (e.g Mathematica, Maple, matlab, maxima,...) and plot the function out.
These days, you can even go online, typing `plot z^2 = x*y+1` into the input box of wolfram alpha and get you a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z^2+%3D+x*y%2B1).

Comment: Well yes, I suppose I should have clarified I mean in like a test situation.

Comment: @HavelTheGreat: Could you please post the whole extremum problem? It would be easier to come to a final result if I saw the problem as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

The function can be written as

$$z=\pm\sqrt{xy+1}.$$

Obviously, if $xy<-1$ then there is no real $z$. Note that $xy<0$ if the signs are different. This means that our function has limitations only on the second and the fourth quadrant.

For a positive $x$ we have to find those negative $y$'s for which $xy<-1$.  So, we have no solution if $$y<-\frac1x.$$

If $x<0$ then $y$ has to be positive and we don't have a solutions if $$y>-\frac1x.$$
(The inequality turned around because we divided by a negative number.)

The following figure depicts in red the domain where there is no solution, and in green where there is solution:

[image]

Alpha plots well depicts the situation. For $+\sqrt{xy+1}$ we have

[image]

And for $-\sqrt{xy+1}$ my Alpha PRO gives

[image]

The moral of my answer was supposed to be that we did not have to use Alpha, since elementary calculations showed the border lines.

Comment: So, how would I identify that this has no endpoints?

Comment: This function does have endpoints: the borderlines between the red and green areas are the endpoints. (I will immediately insert an Alpha plot.)

Comment: Thanks. So if I am using the Lagrange algorithm for instance, and want to ensure that this non-closed surface has no considerable points for maxima/minima, how would I be able to assess that from these inequalities?

Comment: First, see if the values you've got fall in the green region. Second, substitute $y=-\frac1x$ into the original equation and see if the new (one variable) function has larger or smaller values on the border line. (Larger or smaller then the original extrema...)

Comment: In the Alpha plot, what happened to the points where $z=-\sqrt{xy+1}$?

Comment: @DavidK: I am going to add that plot too. Before using Aloha I foresee that the borderline thing will not change and the hills will be dried out lakes.

Comment: @HavelTheGreat, I am eagerly waiting for you feedback. Was my guidance useful or was it not?

Comment: I am still wondering about the "borderline". The actual constraint is $z^2 = xy+1$, not $x=\sqrt{xy+1}$ (which indeed has a boundary) and not $x=-\sqrt{xy+1}$ (which also has a boundary). Each of the latter two equations gives you just half of the constraint surface; put them together, as we should, and we have a hyperboloid with no boundary that I can see. (Yes, you can intersect the hyperboloid with the $x,y$ plane to produce a two-branched curve; but why do that? And if so, why not some other plane?)

Comment: The constraint is, indeed, $z^2=xy+1$. I don't see, however the function (of two variable?) whose extrema we are looking for. But I assume that we are interested in points of real coordinates. In that case the constraint given above is stricter because it makes sense only within the green area. In the green area not only does $z^2=xy+1$ hold but, also, the coordinates of the possible solutions are real. So, I think that the real constraint should be that "find the critical points of ... restricted to the green area."